# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: css, angular, dependencies, installation, materialize

while installing materialize-css in my angular CLI project I got this message in the terminal:

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY materialize-css@0.98.2 npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN angular2-materialize@6.7.2
>   requires a peer of materialize-css@^0.97.8 but none was installed. npm
>   ERR! code 1

what does that mean?

Comment: Do you have `materialize-css@0.98.2` installed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the node_modules of your app and clear the npm cache.
2. Goto **package.json** file and remove the `materialize-css` and
   `angular2-materialize`.
3. Then use the following commands

   ```
   npm install materialize-css@latest --save -g 
   npm install angular2-materialize@latest --save -g
   ```

You will still get the peer dependency on fsevents but not to worry on it.